# Cant get SQL object from another class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms

I have an extension for RefineryCMS. In that extension I need to get data from object Block in the PagesController.

My code:

```
def show
  if should_skip_to_first_child?
    redirect_to refinery.url_for(first_live_child.url) and return
  elsif page.link_url.present?
    redirect_to page.link_url and return
  elsif should_redirect_to_friendly_url?
    redirect_to refinery.url_for(page.url), :status => 301 and return
  end

  @block = Refinery::Blocks::BlocksController::Block.find_by(:name => 'Footer')

  render_with_templates?
end
```

In development the first launch is successful, but after refreshing or redirecting to another site's page:

```
uninitialized constant Refinery::Blocks::BlocksController::Block
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you paste whole code of your controller and model.
I think problem in this line. 
`@block = Refinery::Blocks::BlocksController::Block.find_by(:name => 'Footer')`
You are trying to access from controller.
Use Model name like
`Module::Model.find_by(:name => "Footer")`

Answer: https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms/issues/3051